# Change json val / replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey guys I use a form to get some data and put that in a json.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="label">Gender</div>
            <div>
                <select name="PersonalDataGender" >
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

**JSON:**

```
strJSON =
{
    "PersonalData" : {
        "Gender" : $("[name=PersonalDataGender]").val(), 
    }
}
```

I need it to save 1 if it's man and save 2 if female without changing the val of option  to 1 or 2

Comment: instead of $("[name=PersonalDataGender]").val() use this $("[name=PersonalDataGender] option:selected").val();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var gender = $("[name=PersonalDataGender]").val();   
strJSON =
{
    "PersonalData" : {
        "Gender" : (gender == 'Male' ? 1 : (gender == 'Female' ? 2 : 0)), 
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u5ew5r8/)